# how to select all repeated data in a table without giving any key?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has thousands of data but with repeated ones.
Now i want to select all of them automatically without giving any key.
How can I do that please?

EXAMPLE:

```
|id|name   |email|
---+-------+-----+
|1 |William|same1|
|2 |John   |same1|
|3 |Nabeel |same2|
|4 |Jessica|same3|
|5 |Adam   |same3|
|6 |Albert |same1|
|7 |Mark   |same3|
|8 |Jason  |same3|
```

How to select the only repeated ones?

Comment: Do you only want the column that is repeated, or do you want the full record for each row that has the repeated value?

Comment: You mean like this? SELECT name, email, COUNT(*)
FROM users
GROUP BY name, email
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

Comment: You can use `group by` in your query. ask your question precisely for a better help please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for [COUNT()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-count-with-distinct.php) and [GROUP BY with HAVING](https://www.guru99.com/group-by.html):

```
SELECT name, email, COUNT(*)
FROM users
GROUP BY name, email
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Per @PatrickQ here is one for just the repeated emails:

```
SELECT email, COUNT(*)
FROM users
GROUP BY email
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

.. And here is one that would get repeated names

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*)
FROM users
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

**This one would return the number of names associated with each email address when there are more than one:**

```
SELECT email, COUNT(DISTINCT name)
FROM users
GROUP BY email
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name) > 1
```